# How to create a numbered bullet not in UIwebview but using UItextview

Tags: ios, format, uitextview

The format is similar to below text:

1. I need to create the bullet like this which would be helpful to me in my application and need someone to share the code with me.
2. Remember the UIwebview is not preferable because I don't have to execute the webviewwillload method.
3. Please find the best and easy way to approach this.
4. Also remember there should be indent spacing.

Comment: So this text will display in UIWebView? And is it dynamic?

Comment: Does it need to be editable?